# SPI not working, ATmega328 only sending 1 byte

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, spi

I am trying to get SPI working on an ATmega328. This is my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define ACK 0x7E
#define LONG_TIME 10000

//Initialize SPI Master Device
void spi_init_master (void)
{
    DDRB = (1<<PORTB5)|(1<<PORTB3);              //Set MOSI, SCK as Output
    SPCR = (1<<SPE)|(1<<MSTR); //Enable SPI, Set as Master

}

//Function to send and receive data
unsigned char spi_tranceiver (unsigned char data)
{
    PORTC = 1<<PORTC2;
    PORTC = 0<<PORTC2;

    SPDR = data;                       //Load data into the buffer
    while(!(SPSR)&(1<<SPIF));
    return(SPDR);                      //Return received data
}


//Main
int main(void)
{
    DDRC= 0XFF; 
    spi_init_master();
    spi_tranceiver(6); 
    //spi_tranceiver(6);
    //spi_tranceiver(6); 


}
```

This is the output from the logic analyzer:

[image]

Notice those two comment lines. `spi_tranceiver(6);` If I remove those comments, I should get, from the logic analyzer:

- 3 times the amount of clock pulses for the blue layer.
- 3 times the amount of data sent, and;
- 3 times the amount of PORTC2 pules.

This is not the case. I get the below:

[image]

The device I am trying to SPI with isn't configured correctly. Does this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have the parantheses in the wrong spot while waiting for the SPI transaction to complete. Because the `!` operator has a higher precedence than `&` it will be trying to do a bitwise not of the `SPSR` register first. Instead you want something like this:

```
while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))
    ;
```

At the moment presumably that wait is returning immediately so the `SPDR` register is getting set three times in rapid succession without enough time for the data to be transferred.

Comment: many thanks! I have spent many many hours on this!

Comment: Also, assuming that PORTC2 is the SS/CS line, that should be held low for the entirety of your SPI 'transaction', and should be taken out of your `spi_tranceiver` function and moved to somewhere surrounding that.